# Map an observable nested object to another object

Tags: angular, typescript, mapping, observable, rxjs6

I am trying to map a response from an API call to a let's say a Product object. I can't seem to find a way to do this properly.

The response is in the following structure:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "keyboard",
      "details": {
        "parent": 1,
        "price": 50,
        "other": "info"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "mouse",
      "details": {
        "parent": 2,
        "other": "info",
        "price": 20
      }
    }
  ],
  "total-records": 2,
  "more": "something"
}
```

The response details order cannot be guaranteed. (Note price in detail).I am trying to map the object above to a single new object which contains only following properties:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "keyboard",
    "price": 50
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "mouse",
    "price": 20
}
```

I am using angular and Observables to get the data. Now I am getting the value, mapping it, and can either just get the details or the 1st level object properties such as `data.id` or `data.name`. However getting details such as price is a bit confusing to me.

I have researched a lot about mergemap, flatmap, even lodash and countless hours trying to figure it out but I can't seem to find a correct way to do it.

Can I use perhaps filter in the combination of a map to achieve this?
Any information is highly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    //Get by criteria
    this.productService
      .get(url, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((items: Response<Product>) => {
          this.details = items["details"].filter(
            // Filter possible null values
            details=> details!==null;
          );
          this.header = items
        }),
        tap(() => console.log(this.header))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
  
  // Header is level 1 info like name and id
  // Detail is level 2 info like price.
  // I have to have a filter on the details because sometimes
```

Comment: before trying to answer :   you are not capturing the "data" attribut from the answer so I don't really understand what you want to do. You are treating "details" as an Array (using filter) but it's an object. You want the result into a single new object (but without attribut) so I suppose it's an array (array of Product ? )

Comment: You're right the resulting new object is an array of Products

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't rely on RxJS there, but on plain old Javascript.

To map your object to the one you expect, try this :

```
this.productService
  .get(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((items: Response<Product>) => items
      .map(item => ({ id: item.id, name: item.name, price: item.details && item.details.price || '?' }))),
    tap(mappedItems => console.log(mappedItems))
  )
  .subscribe(mappedItems => this.header = mappedItems);
```

I Also took the liberty to move your code around a little bit to make it clearer (for instance, doing something in the subscribe instead of the map directly).

What this code does is mapping the Observable, making it return a new set of data.

The new set of data returned is also a mapping, but a mapping of your actual data, not of an Observable.

With the mapped data, you can now apply it to your headers, which is made in the subscribe.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this out. Not sure why it is saying mapped item is undefined.But assigning the new object at map instead of subscribe works. Also the tap is logging undefined.

Comment: You should have an error if your `details` object isn't defined in your object. I have updated my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange way of working to asign "global" from inside a RxJS operator. Those var should be added from the subscribe.  And the way to capture data is also strange.

You are never capturing the "data" attribut from the response and you are treating "details" like an array but in your response it's simple object.

Following what's your API is returing, 1 objects with at least 3 attributes 
**data** a list of product,
**total records**,
**more**...,

What you could do :

```
this.productService
  .get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      map((res) => res.data), // extract data attribut
      map((data) => {
        return data.map((aProd) => {   //map the product and take only id, name, price
          return {
            id: aProd.id,
            name: aProd.name,
            price: aProd.details && aProd.details.price
          };
        });
      })).subscribe((productList) => {
        console.log(productList);
      });
```